# Java being able to choose wether to add or subract

Tags: java, if-statement

I have two question, first is why cant I add an operator , I can add first and 2nd integer but not an operator.

2nd question is I need to create a never ending loop is there an easier way than the while loop? basically the idea is that if for example they choose * if will say wrong operator please try again

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Uppgift5 {
public static void main (String[] args){

    int tal1, tal2;
    int sum = 0;
    int sub=0;
    String operator;


    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("write in first digit");
    tal1 = input.nextInt();


    System.out.println("Write in 2nd digit ");
    tal2 = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter + to add and - subtract ");
    operator = input.nextLine();


    while (operator.equals('-') || operator.equals('+')|| operator.equals('*')  || operator.equals(('/')) ){

    if (operator.equals("+")){
        sum = tal1+tal2;
        System.out.println("the sum is " + sum);
    }

    else if (operator.equals("-")){
        sub = tal1-tal2;
        System.out.println("the subtracted value  is " + sub);

    }

    System.out.println("You have put in the wrong operator, your options are + or -");
}

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The `nextInt` method does not consume the whitespace characters (newline) that you input when you press the carriage return on your keyboard. When you then call

```
operator = input.nextLine();
```

All that reads is that new line character. You need to add an extra

```
nextLine();
```

call after the `nextInt()` so that it can consume the danglign `\n` (or `\r\n` depending on your system) character.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

System.out.println("write in first digit");
tal1 = input.nextInt();

System.out.println("Write in 2nd digit ");
tal2 = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter + to add and - subtract ");
operator = input.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a loop that will keep running until valid input is provided and is different to your `while` construct, try something along these lines:

```
String input;
do {
    input = getInput(); //Replace this with however you get your input
} while(!(input.equals("+") || input.equals("-")));
```

If you want the user to be informed, however, you will need to use a `while` loop similar to how you are at the moment. There aren't many types of loop in Java, and the `while` loop is about as easy as they come. A piece of code that informs the user can go something like the following:

```
String input;
while(true) {
    input = getInput();
    if(input.equals("+") || input.equals("-")) break; //Exit loop if valid input
    System.out.println("Invalid input");
}

//Do arithmetic here
```

As for your first question, I'm not entirely clear as to what you mean by 'adding an operator'. Can you clarify this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer from your other post!

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class tt {
public static void main (String[] args){

int tal1, tal2;
int sum = 0;
int sub=0;
String operator = "";


Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
Scanner input2 = new Scanner (System.in);

System.out.println("write in first digit");
tal1 = input.nextInt();


System.out.println("Write in 2nd digit ");
tal2 = input.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter + to add and - subtract ");

while (true){

operator = input2.nextLine();
if (operator.equals("+")){
    sum = tal1+tal2;
    System.out.println("the sum is " + sum);
}
else if (operator.equals("-")){
    sub = tal1-tal2;
    System.out.println("the subtracted value  is " + sub);

}

if (operator.equals("*") || operator.equals("/")){
    System.out.println("You have put in the wrong operator, your options are + or -");
    break;
  }
  }
 }
}
```